# How to create new functions for String class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to check the type of strings that I encounter:

```
class String
    def is_i?
        /\A[-+]?\d+\z/ === self
    end

    def is_path?
        pn = Pathname.new(self)
        pn.directory?
    end     
end

def check(key)
    puts case key
    when is_i?
        puts "Could be a number"
    when is_path?
        puts "This is a path"
    else
        puts "Ok"
    end
end
```

When I run `check("1345425")` I get the following error:

```
undefined method `is_i?' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

What should I do to correct it?

Comment: Your check method is not defined on the String class but you're calling is_i? on it. Try writing when key.is_i? and when key.is_path? instead.

Comment: The methods you defined on string are fine.  Your problem is you've misunderstood how `case` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined functions on `String` instance, hence:

```
def check(key)
    puts case
         when key.is_i?
           "Could be a number"
         when key.is_path?
           "This is a path"
         else
           "Ok"
         end
end
```

or

```
def check(key)
    puts case key
         when ->(s) { s.is_i? }
           "Could be a number"
         when ->(s) { s.is_path? }
           "This is a path"
         else
           "Ok"
         end
end
```

*UPD* Please also note that I removed superfluous subsequent calls to `puts`.

Answer (score 1):

Your check method isn't defined on the String class, so when you write when is_i? and when is_path? it is trying to call those methods on your main, hence the error.

You should call these methods on your String object (key) like this:

```
...
when key.is_i?
...
when key.is_path?
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You may change it like this

```
class String
  def is_i?
    /\A[-+]?\d+\z/ === self
  end

  def is_path?
    pn = Pathname.new(self)
    pn.directory?
  end
end

def check(hash_key)
  puts case hash_key
  when Proc.new { hash_key.is_i? }
    return "Could be a number"
  when Proc.new { hash_key.is_path? }
    return "This is a path"
  else
    return "Ok"
  end
end
```

Running `check('1312312')` in `irb` returns result as `"Could be a number"`

Comment: Please _never_ use `return` in ruby like this.